# SQL Server Cannot Read Latinic Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in SQL Server with column `Name nvarchar(max)`. When I try to save data as

```
insert into Months(Name)
values('Март');
```

and then see what is saved I see only `???????` symbols.

What configuration should I do ?

Comment: Likely an artifact of the character-set you have chosen for display than a database issue. Please supply details of the font you are using to inspect the data values.

Comment: it surprised me that all the chars in the `Март` are unicode characters, I just thought the last letter `т` is the only one (hence the hard-to-understand problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to insert it as unicode first - as it is a double byte character. This is what the `N` does.

```
   insert into Months(Name)
    values(N'Март');
```

`N` tells SQL Server the following string is a "Unicode constant string"

Comment: Is this the only way ?

Comment: In the case of parameterized queries (instead of string literals), specify `nvarchar` as the parameter data type.  The N string prefix is required only for `Unicode` literals.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows,

```
INSERT INTO Months(Name) VALUES(N'Март');
```